# Hide application is greyed out

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software, ventura

Sometimes "Hide ... application" is greyed out. It usually works fine but I can't determine what causes it.

For example, in Chrome, **Hide Google Chrome** is greyed out and the only way I can see my desktop is to do <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> which puts annoying grey lines around my screen.

Any ideas what might be causing the hide application option to be greyed out? I tried to replicate the problem but since I don't know what causes it and it happens seldom I couldn't.

Comment: I have run across situations where I have inadvertently hidden Finder (I think) as the one window left on the screen won't hide. But if I click on the desktop to activate Finder and then back to that app, it hides just fine. Don't have a solution but maybe that is what is happening?

Comment: @SteveChambers :3333 thankss

Answer (score 1):

As Steve Chambers has pointed out if you inadvertently hide finder os doesnt let you hide other applications maybe because its the last active window i dont know why it works like this :? but not hiding finder seems to fix the issue thank you all for the responses

Comment: This makes no sense at all. It's perfectly possible to Hide every running app from the Dock [or by opt-clicking], one after another, until all you have left is the Desktop picture… unless you're running in fullscreen. Fullscreen & Hide are completely incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide a fullscreened app… there's nothing behind it, technically, not even the desktop.

btw,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>   is 'new bookmark' by default, so you'd have to tell us what non-standard command you have it set to.

Comment: Well he's probably using cmd+d to "hide app" ?

Comment: @Thinkr - then why would it 'put annoying grey lines round the screen'? It would simply not work.

Comment: Oh you're right! :)

Comment: `Mission Control` -- `Show Desktop` performs that task of showing the Desktop with the surrounding grey lines. I have it assigned to `hot corner` lower right ... but I do not see a way in Sys Pref to assign  Cmd ⌘  D  as a keyboard shortcut for show desktop. Clever -- mimics Windows keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @BobK77 - you need to ask that as a new question. No-one but me will ever see it buried down here in a comment.

Comment: Yes, quite so @Tetsujin. Thank you.  Glad that you got to see that comment. :-)  Was not really a question ... just responding to an earlier comment as to how is it that one could use command+D to see the desktop ...  but, it puts "annoying grey lines" around the screen.